# py2exe :RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, python-3.4, py2exe, python.net, python-jira

I am facing a problem while generating an exe file.

Python 3.4.3,
py2exe (0.9.2.2)

The following site packages are used in my script:

jira (1.0.10),
pythonnet (2.3.0),
tkinter

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import os
import sys
setup(console=[os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'OMNIgui.py')])
```

outout in command promt:

```css
C:\work\Workspace\OMNItool\src>python setup.py py2exe
    running py2exe
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "setup.py", line 32, in <module>
        setup(console=[os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'OMNIgui.py')]
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 188, in run
        self._run()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 267, in _run
        builder.analyze()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\runtime.py", line 173, in analyze
        target.analyze(mf)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\runtime.py", line 74, in analyze
        modulefinder.run_script(self.script)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 86, in run_script
        self._scan_code(mod.__code__, mod)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 394, in _scan_code
        self.safe_import_hook(name, mod, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 138, in safe_import_hook

        self.import_hook(name, caller, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
        module = self._gcd_import(name)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
        return self._find_and_load(name)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_load
        self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 394, in _scan_code
        self.safe_import_hook(name, mod, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 138, in safe_import_hook
        self.import_hook(name, caller, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
        module = self._gcd_import(name)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
        return self._find_and_load(name)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 288, in _find_and_load
        self._gcd_import(parent)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
        return self._find_and_load(name)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_load
        self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 394, in _scan_code
        self.safe_import_hook(name, mod, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 138, in safe_import_hook
        self.import_hook(name, caller, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
        module = self._gcd_import(name)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
        return self._find_and_load(name)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_load
        self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 135, in safe_import_hook
        self._info(name, caller, fromlist, level)
    RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

please help me how to come out with this error.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: why don't you switch to pyinstaller or cx_freeze? py2exe was not updated for long time and is not maintained anymore.

Comment: I tried using cx_freeze but the same result am getting a diiferent error. Is there any way to overcome the error using cx_freeze/pyinstaller.

Comment: can you show error from pyinstaller?